# re do not work, strange characters

Tags: python, regex, string

```
textfields="""Conjugation of suorittaa """ 
stry2= """Conjugation"""
stryc=re.compile(stry2, re.DOTALL)
print 'textfields=', textfields, '  stry2=', stry2
LtryM=re.search(stryc, textfields); print 'LtryM', LtryM
```

I could not find with re word """Conjugation""" in string """Conjugation of suorittaa """. 
I the end i printed word ans string.
Appeared that instead of  """Conjugation""" i got printed word  """xxxConjugation""", where xxx are strange characters.

How i can solve this. I tried also to encode both strings to 'utf-8'. Result is the same. 
These strange characters appear only infront of word, are not visible in conjug.py.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not reproducible, based on the information that you have supplied:

```
>>> import re
>>> textfields="""Conjugation of suorittaa """
>>> stry2= """Conjugation"""
>>> stryc=re.compile(stry2, re.DOTALL)
>>> print 'textfields=', textfields, '  stry2=', stry2
textfields= Conjugation of suorittaa    stry2= Conjugation
>>> LtryM=re.search(stryc, textfields); print 'LtryM', LtryM
LtryM <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0195A870>
>>> LtryM.group(0)
'Conjugation'
>>> print repr(textfields)
'Conjugation of suorittaa '
>>> print repr(stry2)
'Conjugation'
>>>
```

Try reproducing it yourself, in a manner like the above which can be copied/pasted into SO and shows exactly what I did and what the results were.

[Python 2.7.1; Windows 7 32-bit]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `search` and `match` return a match object if you have a capture group. To get the behaviour you are expecting, use `findall`.

```
In [23]: textfields="""Conjugation of suorittaa """ 

In [24]: stry2= """Conjugation"""

In [25]: ls = re.findall(stry2 , textfields )

In [26]: ls
Out[26]: ['Conjugation']
```

If this is not your query, please explain a bit more what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code should find the match fine. Note that `re.search` returns a `MatchObject`, which you shouldn't print out directly - you might want to print out the text it matched instead:

```
print LtryM.group(0)
```

This should print 'Conjugation'.